# Python- Passing 2 sets of **kwargs into same Class. Is it possible?

Tags: python, tkinter

Lets say I have a class named `NewEntry` with 2 tkinter widgets, `ttk.Entry` and `ttk.Button`, which I want to pass each one of them `**kw_ent` and `**kw_but` for Entry and Button widget respectively, to enable a code flexibilty when using this class.

But, as shown in code below, defining 2 kwargs yields an syntax error (which is quite obvious when coding it this way).

Is there a way to pass 2 kwargs?

```
class NewEntry(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw_ent, **kw_but):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master

        self.ent_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.ent = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.ent_var, **kw_ent)
        self.ent.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text='Button', command=self.but_callback, **kw_but)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.ent.bind('<FocusIn>', self.clear_ent)

        self.init_vals()

    def init_vals(self):
        self.ent_var.set("Enter value")
        self.ent['foreground'] = 'red'

    def clear_ent(self, event):
        self.ent_var.set('')
        self.ent['foreground'] = '#4c4c4c'

    def restore_ent(self, event):
        self.init_vals()

    def but_callback(self):
        print(self.ent_var.get())
        sleep(1)
        self.init_vals()


root = tk.Tk()
a = NewEntry(root, width=13)
a.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How would python decide which key-word arguments belong to `**kw_ent` and which belong to `**kw_but`? Just pass two separate `dict` objects as normal parameters: `kw_ent, kw_but`.

Comment: As wrote- I know this is not the way to solve it from that particular reason

Comment: You could `.update()` one dict with the other first, then passing it into the function call.

Comment: Right. So I'm not sure what you question is. I mean, if you just make the parameters normal, positional parameters and make sure to pass seperate `dict` objects, your code wiould work.

Comment: @Evert can you be more specific ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga in general, using **kwargs gives the flexibilty to define only parameters you wish rather than define what parameter needs to be defined, and give them a default value. I seek a way to have this abilty when using 2 widgets that each one of them get its own **kwargs.

Comment: ... Dude, I already explained, you can't do this, Python function signatures don't support this. Also, `**kwargs` *don't* let you give them defaults. IMO the best solution, which lets you define **only the arguments you want**, is to **just to use two separate  normal arguments** and just pass those as `dict` objects. That is all you have to change, your code will work as *written already*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga OK Dude :) , using a `dict` with a defined, defaulted values- goes without saying, I was curious to know if there is another way. TNX !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass 2 kwargs?

Yes quite simply: don't use the `**kwargs` notation.

```
class NewEntry(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, kw_ent=None, kw_but=None):
        if kw_ent is None:
            kw_ent = {}
        if kw_but is None:
            kw_but = {}

        # your existsing code here
```

You will of course have to be a bit more explicit when instanciating `NewEntry` - assuming that in `a = NewEntry(root, width=13)`, `width` was supposed to be part of `kw_ent` you'll need:

```
a = NewEntry(root, kw_ent={"width":13})
```

As a side note, you may want to consider a more readable naming scheme than "ent" or "but" - "entry" and "button" come to mind... Short doesn't mean cryptic and 3 letters identifiers won't make your code any faster (but they sure make it less readable).

Comment: thank you. 1) regrading notation- It was an example and not part of a real code ( just to make my point ), still thank you for that. 2) As suggested in other comment, I understand this is the way solving it